# Combine Multiple Group of columns from 1 sheet to 1 master data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to combine data I createed for my workers to 1 master sheet, I created one sheet for all the workers so they can check or backup to other if the job not yet done.

I'm trying to use a query or importrange but I'm not the getting desired results.

Here is the example of data in google sheet, hope someone can help.

Thanks a lot

Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1snx8EbFR_YhDflqR5rYWdDrN3ORSi7XAo5Ex3bQxPzE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a solution inside your sheet. We combine:

1. ARRAYFORMULA - To stack them under each other using { }
2. QUERY - To filter out the blank rows
3. IMPORTRANGE - to get the data

**SOLUTION** - in the same spreadsheet

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
  QUERY({Data1!A1:E},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1);
   QUERY({Data2!A1:E},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
     })
```

**SOLUTION** - with importrange from a other spreadsheet. (same a above but get data via importrange)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1snx8EbFR_YhDflqR5rYWdDrN3ORSi7XAo5Ex3bQxPzE","Data1!A1:E"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1);
    QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1snx8EbFR_YhDflqR5rYWdDrN3ORSi7XAo5Ex3bQxPzE","Data2!A1:E"),"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
       })
```

I hope this what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(""&{Data1!A1:E; Data2!A1:E},
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

or:

```
=FILTER({Data1!A1:E; Data2!A1:E}, 
    ""<>{Data1!A1:A; Data2!A1:A})
```

[image]